# PHP If statement returns false on MySQL boolean column return

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement, boolean

I am using the CodeIgniter framework. I'm working on the user authentication portion of my website. In my 'users' table of my MySQL database I have a column that I declared as a BOOLEAN (I am aware that it really is a TINYINT(1)) called 'verified' that denotes whether or not a user's email address has been verified. When I try to test the value of this column, my IF statement always evaluates to FALSE, even though I know for a fact the value is 1. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public function authenticate_user(){
    $pw = hash('sha512', $this->salt1 . $this->input->post('password') . $this->salt2);
    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['email' => $email, 'password' => $pw]);
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        $row = $query->row_array();
        //die("verified = ".$row['verified']); <-This line shows 'verified = 1' consistently when uncommented.
        if($row['verified'] == 1){
            $this->session->set_userdata([
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'email' => $email,
            'login_time' => time(),
            'last_activity' => time(),
            'session_valid' => TRUE
            ]);
            return true;
        }
        else return 'unverified';
    }
    else return false;
}
```

When the credentials are correct, this function always returns 'unverified' and no session variables are set. The function exhibits the correct behavior when the credentials are incorrect. I have confirmed in phpMyAdmin that the column is 1, and I have confirmed that 1 is returned from the database by uncommenting the die() statement above. I have tried using true and '1' (string) in place of the integer 1 and have gotten the same result. Am I doing something wrong? Does CodeIgniter preprocess database returns in a way that would make this not work?

Comment: since the value is boolean, have you tried just doing `if($row['verified'])`?

Comment: What is shown when doing a `var_dump($row['verified'])` or `var_dump($row)`?

Comment: About the tinyint(1): MySQL uses it on booleans and expects the user to consider zero as false and non-zero as true. You can insert on that column a value bigger than 1. Therefore, using >=1 or >0 when testing for true would be a better practice.

Comment: var_dump($row) = array(12) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["email"]=> string(18) "xxxx@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(128) "ec396f56c87f6172e11b2af8f531c0209fa824991fb63392cbf37baa6134a7140cd75e619efb815274047e90f1ff5d7eee329e48ebf1093f054ba5164cb52834" ["name"]=> string(4) "Eric" ["date_registered"]=> string(19) "2015-07-25 12:37:29" ["date_verified"]=> string(19) "2015-07-25 12:42:06" ["verified"]=> string(1) "1" ["code"]=> string(4) "null" ["locked"]=> string(1) "0" ["date_locked"]=> NULL ["reason_locked"]=> NULL ["last_pw_change"]=> NULL }

Comment: var_dump($row["verified"]) = string(1) "1"

Comment: So I tried @Sean's suggestion of using `if($row['verified'])` and it works now. It does not make sense to me how that `== 1`, `== '1'`, and `== true` evaluate to false, but the suggested code does. Regardless, thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Sean, your suggestion works. I'm not sure why PHP evaluates it differently than when using the == operator. The way it works is:

```
if($row['verified'])
```

Thank you for you help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `empty()` function in the `if` clause:

```
if(!empty($row['verified'])){
     $this->session->set_userdata([
         'name' => $row['name'],
         'email' => $email,
         'login_time' => time(),
         'last_activity' => time(),
         'session_valid' => TRUE
     ]);
     return true;
}
```